# What is the procedure to fill/send/approve a flight plan to the ATS network from outside?

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-planning, air-traffic-management, dispatch

We are planning to develop an app that allows general pilots to fill/send a flight plan to the ATS. We're wondering to know if it is needed to have a regular access (register access or account) to the ATS network (thru AMHS or other way).

The idea is to automate the process through an app for general pilots.

For example, Garmin Pilot's app works and offers same solution., among many other related solutions for pilots.

Comment: I think you may rephrase to indicate that you want to know what is the current procedure to send/approve a flight plan so that you can automate through a software you are developing.

Comment: As far as I know, AMHS supports the filing of flight plans, but AFTN only supports doing that for military users.

Comment: thank @ManuH Actually you are right, it seems more accurate but on the other hand what I am also looking for is for web systems or external providers well known that could allow us to do this.

Comment: @JuanJimenez as far as I understand as AMHS is currently the standard for ATS messaging; my focus point is how to send information to this network (AKA "getting access") in order to fill/send/get approval for a flight  plan

Comment: @Carlos please, edit your question to make it clear at first reading (add precision and concision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EUROCONTROLs „business-to-business web services“ you can file and manage flight Plans (including IFPS validation) as well as check details about the filed flights e.g. departure and arrival messages or where the aircraft is currently.

After a registration (you have to proof you are eligible to use the service) you do not need any ATFM connection at all - you implement the API features of B2B services into your app and that‘s it.

For more details and the conditions check: https://www.eurocontrol.int/service/network-manager-business-business-b2b-web-services

Comment: Appreciated to your response.